# C# multiple checkboxes

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have 10 `checkboxes` on my form. They are named checkBox1, checkBox2, ..., checkBox10.
At the moment my code looks like this:

```
 if(checkBox1.Checked)
   Call MyFunction(1);  
 if(checkBox2.Checked) 
   Call MyFunction(2);
```

etc
Because the argument I pass to my function is the same as the `checkbox` number, I would like to use a for loop, so that for each `checkbox_i`, I should call `MyFunction(i)`

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very safe, but simple way:

```
int index = 1; 
foreach (var checkBox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    if (checkBox.Checked)
    {
        MyFunction(index);
    }

    index++;
}
```

Next idea is safer, but not very elegant:

```
foreach (var checkBox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
    if (checkBox.Checked)
    {
        int index = int.Parse(checkBox.Name.Substring(8));
        MyFunction(index);
    }
}
```

Ultimately, best is to populate `.Tag` property of all checkboxes with appropriate indices. In this solution you could even skip some checkboxes like this:

```
foreach (var checkBox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(c => c.Checked))
{
    int? index = checkBox.Tag as int;

    if (index.HasValue)
    {
        MyFunction(index.Value);
    }
}
```

And even more readable way would be to have a list of checkboxes you are interested in this process in your form's constructor for example:

```
relevantCheckBoxes = new List<CheckBox>();
relevantCheckBoxes.Add(this.checkBox1);
relevantCheckBoxes.Add(this.checkBox3);
// etc.
```

And then:

```
for (int index = 0;index < relevantCheckboxes.Count;++index)
{
    if (relevantCheckboxes[index].Checked)
    {
        MyFunction(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `Form` has 11th checkBox for which `MyFunction(int)` suppose to not call?

Comment: Thank you very much Bartosz. I was getting close to one of the solutions you presented, but yours are more elegant. In the end I opted for your second sample. I had to change the code to int index = int.Parse(checkBox.Name.Remove(0, 8)); because it gives an error.

Comment: Personally, I like the list approach the best because it is the least likely to cause unexpected behavior as new checkboxes are placed on your form in the future!

Answer (score 1):

ok there are property in any control name Name check this pesodo code

```
Checkbox t=CheckBox(object);
var number=t.name.substring("checkbox".length,name.length-"checkbox".length) // to get only number or you can split name by regular expression

myfunction(int.parse(number));
// try this code and and ask here agine if any problem due to I can't test it now
```