# C# Checkboxes Optimisation

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, checkbox

I have a panel with 5 checkboxes in it, one for each weekday. The user in this scenario is booking appointments on the week. 
I have a **WeeklyBooking class**. This class has five bools, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday. By default, all bools are set to false. When a checkbox is checked, the corresponding bool becomes true.

```
        private void CheckCBs(WeeklyBooking week)
    {
        if (MondayCB.Checked)
        {
            week.monday = true;
        }
        if (TuesdayCB.Checked)
        {
            week.tuesday = true;
        }
        if (WednesdayCB.Checked)
        {
            week.wednesday = true;
        }
        if (ThursdayCB.Checked)
        {
            week.thursday = true;
        }
        if (FridayCB.Checked)
        {
            week.friday = true;
        }
        return;
    }
```

This is a method I call in a different method while I build the object to be put in an SQL Table. 
Does Anybody have any advice for how to optimise this method? 
- Thanks.

Comment: Never did [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# multiple checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949299/c-sharp-multiple-checkboxes)

Comment: You can begin by eliminating all those entirely superfluous and utterly annoying curly braces.  I think that would go a long way towards optimizing your function.

Comment: I wonder what happens if the user clicks Monday, then changes the selection to Friday...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `if()` statements are not necessary. The `Checked` property of `ComboBox` is already a `bool` and will be false if the checkbox is unchecked. Simply assign the value of the `Checked` property to your `WeeklyBooking` object properties:

```
private void CheckCBs(WeeklyBooking week)
{
    week.monday = MondayCb.Checked;
    week.tuesday = TuesdayCb.Checked;
    week.wednesday = WednesdayCb.Checked;
    week.thursday = ThursdayCb.Checked;
    week.friday= FridayCb.Checked;
}
```